# Python function: how to use the argument in kwargs

Tags: python, keyword-argument

When writing functions with **kwargs, the syntax becomes not as clean as without it. For example

```
def func(x, y):
    print(x + y)
```

will become

```
def func(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs["x"] + kwargs["y"])
```

Any suggestions to make calling kwargs nicer and more clean?

Comment: What was wrong with your first version?

Comment: It's not wrong. Just a toy example... the problem is If I have a larger function, how can I avoid writing so many kwargs["key"]?

Comment: You can avoid that by not using kwargs.

Comment: Yes... But in that case, I will not able to write functions with variable number of arguments. Is there any good convention to better write function with kwargs?

Comment: kwargs are useful if you want the user to be apply to add kwargs for a function that you call. For example, see [Pandas Plot Function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html). It takes kwargs and passes them to `matplotlib`.

Comment: If you post an example of a function you'd like to write with adaptable arguments, someone can probably suggest a good way to write it. The function you've posted is not a good use of kwargs, which is why it looks so awkward.

Comment: @khelwood thank you for your feedback! I will improve my example post next time! Actually my original question is writing a number of subclasses each overrides a same method in a common superclass. The problem is these subclass methods have different number of arguments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argparse` mentioned in the other answer uses `kwargs` a lot.  It gives a lot of flexibility when handling a large number optional parameters, but the syntax is not 'simple. You need to handle the case where the user does not provide a value.  The dictionary `get` is good for that:

```
In [241]: def func(**kwargs): 
     ...:     print(kwargs) 
     ...:     x = kwargs.get('x',0) 
     ...:     y = kwargs.get('y',0) 
     ...:     return x + y 
     ...:      
     ...:                                                                       
In [242]: func(x=1, y=2)                                                        
{'x': 1, 'y': 2}
Out[242]: 3
In [243]: func(**{'x':1, 'y':2})                                                
{'x': 1, 'y': 2}
Out[243]: 3
```

Also use `if 'x' in kwargs:` or `for key in kwargs:`

With keyword parameters, you can use the same `**dict` style of input:

```
In [244]: def func(x=0, y=2): 
     ...:     return x + y                                                                       
In [245]: func(**{'x':1, 'y':2})                                                
Out[245]: 3
```

You could unpack the `kwargs` with:

```
In [246]: def func(**kwargs): 
     ...:     x, y = kwargs.values() 
     ...:     return x + y 
     ...:                                                                       
In [247]: func(**{'x':1, 'y':2})                                                
Out[247]: 3
```

but in that case you might as well use `*args`:

```
In [248]: def func(*args): 
     ...:     x, y = args 
     ...:     return x + y 
     ...:                                                                       
In [249]: func(1,2)                                                             
Out[249]: 3
```

Part of the code for `argparse.Namespace`:

```
class Namespace(_AttributeHolder):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for name in kwargs:
            setattr(self, name, kwargs[name])
```

This converts the dictionary keys into object attributes.   `argparse` also notes that you can go the other direction with `vars(args)`, getting a dictionary from an object's attributes.

Comment: thank you for the answer. The .get() is very helpful in my case.

Answer (score 3):

A suggestion is to use `Namespace` from `argparse` (available in the standard library) and use normal attribute access:

```
from argparse import Namespace

def somefunc(**kwargs):
    kwargs = Namespace(**kwargs)
    print(kwargs.foo)
    print(kwargs.bar)
```

Executing:

```
In [9]: somefunc(foo='hello', bar='world')
hello
world
```